# How are basic data types (strings and integers) implemented in Python and Perl

Tags: python, perl

I've been wondering lately how various operations I perform on basic types like strings and integers work in terms of performance, and I figure I could get a much better idea of this if I knew how those basic types were implemented (i.e. I've heard strings and integers are immutable in Python. Does that mean any operation that modifies one character in a string is O(n) because a completely new string has to be created? How about adding numbers?)

I'm curious about this in both Python and Perl, and felt silly asking basically the same question twice, so I'm just wrapping it into one.

If you can include some example operation costs with your answer, that would make it even more helpful.

Comment: `some_string[5] = 'a'` is O(1) in Python - the `TypeError` doesn't get more expensive for longer strings ;)

Comment: Crap. Right. Sorry, my Python is a bit rusty. I guess what I mean is: is there a way to modify one letter in a string without copying the whole thing (i.e. faster than O(n))?

Comment: If you have Python 3 and you want to use `bytes`, then yes.

Comment: `bytearray` in Python 2.6+ offers mutable byte strings that share all the properties of normal strings except hashability (and usability as dictionary keys, etc.) You can't modify a single letter in a unicode string without copying the string though.

Comment: This probably should be two separate questions.

Comment: @Daenyth, exactly.  There aren't many people who are familiar with the implementation details of both Perl and Python, and you can't pick two "best" answers on SO.

Comment: Yeah, in retrospect, I probably should have asked two questions. Is there anything I can do to edit it into two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python, `some_string[5] = 'a'` would be an error, but the closest equivalent operation, `some_string = some_string[5:] + 'a' + some_string[6:]` would indeed be O(n). But that's not just true of immutable objects. The same is true for concatenating lists: `[1,2,3] + [4,5,6]` generates a new list and is O(n).

Adding numbers creates a new value, but generally the resulting value is always the same size in memory, so it's O(1). Of course that only holds with small ints. Once you hit some threshold (20 digits on my machine), suddenly ints take up a variable amount of space. I don't know how that effects asymptotic performance.

However, I found that it doesn't seem to have even a significant effect even near `log10(n) == 1000`:

```
>>> times = [timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt.format(10 ** i, 10 ** i), number=100) for i in range(1000)]
>>> sum(times) * 1.0 / len(times)
3.0851364135742186e-06
>>> times[-1]
3.0994415283203125e-06
```

For strings, the asymptotic performance hit is more immediately apparent:

```
>>> stmt = 's[:5] + "a" + s[6:]'
>>> setup = 's = "b" * {0}'
>>> times = [timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt, setup=setup.format(i), number=10) for i in range(100000)]
>>> sum(times) * 1.0 / len(times)
6.2434492111206052e-05
>>> times[-1]
0.0001220703125
```

The execution time for the last operation is well below the average. And the trend is pretty steady:

```
>>> for t in times[0:100000:10000]:
...     print t
... 
5.00679016113e-06
1.31130218506e-05
2.90870666504e-05
3.88622283936e-05
5.10215759277e-05
6.19888305664e-05
7.41481781006e-05
8.48770141602e-05
9.60826873779e-05
0.000108957290649
```

Still, operations like these on small strings are pretty cheap.

---

To expand on your other questions, indexed access is O(1) on both lists and strings.

```
>>> stmt = 'x = s[{0}] + s[{1}] + s[{2}]'
>>> setup = 's = "a" * {0}'
>>> times = [timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt.format(i / 2, i / 3, i / 4), setup=setup.format(i + 1), number=10) for i in range(1000000)]
>>> sum(times) * 1.0 / len(times)
3.6441037654876707e-06
>>> times[-1]
3.0994415283203125e-06
```

Likewise with lists:

```
>>> stmt = 'x = s[{0}] + s[{1}] + s[{2}]'
>>> setup = 's = ["a"] * {0}'
>>> times = [timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt.format(i / 2, i / 3, i / 4), setup=setup.format(i + 1), number=10) for i in range(100000)]
>>> sum(times) * 1.0 / len(times)
2.8617620468139648e-06
>>> times[-1]
1.9073486328125e-06
```

Slicing copies both strings *and* lists, and is therefore O(n) with `n == len(slice)`. There is no "good" way to replace one letter of a string, although I want to emphasize that the "bad" way is good enough most of the time. If you want a "good" way, use a different data type; manipulate a list and join it when a string is required; or use a StringIO object. [This page](http://skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) has some useful information on concatenating different built-in Python datatypes.

Finally, since you're really interested in the internals, I dug up the `struct` declaration of `PyStringObject` in [`stringobject.h`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Include/stringobject.h?view=markup) (from version 2.7; 3+ probably looks different). It's about what you'd expect -- a c string with some extra bells and whistles:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
```

(`PyObject_VAR_HEAD` is a c preprocessor macro that expands to something like the below depending on rules explained [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/structures.html#PyObject_HEAD).)

```
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    PyTypeObject *ob_type;
    Py_ssize_t ob_size;
```

Continuing...

```
    long ob_shash;
    int ob_sstate;
    char ob_sval[1];

    /* Invariants:
     *     ob_sval contains space for 'ob_size+1' elements.
     *     ob_sval[ob_size] == 0.
     *     ob_shash is the hash of the string or -1 if not computed yet.
     *     ob_sstate != 0 iff the string object is in stringobject.c's
     *       'interned' dictionary; in this case the two references
     *       from 'interned' to this object are *not counted* in ob_refcnt.
     */
} PyStringObject;
```

Lists have a [similar structure](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Include/listobject.h?view=markup) -- c arrays with extra bells and whistles -- but aren't null terminated and generally have extra preallocated storage space.

Needless to say... much of this this applies *only* to cPython -- [PyPy](http://pypy.org/), [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/), and [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) probably all look totally different!

Comment: For a list, I can modify one item with lst[5] = 'a' in O(1) time, because I don't need to create a new list or do anything with the items around the one I'm modifying (note: the list is stored as a dynamic array, so I'm just replacing one of the pointers in the array).

If I have a very long string, where the cost of creating a new one is great, is there no efficient way for me to just replace one letter? What if I join and then split?

Comment: Also, what about the slice operation, like str[:5]? How efficient is that, and how does it even work on a string? If I knew how strings were stored, I'd be more comfortable answering such questions, I think.

Comment: @Eli, I added some more detail -- hope this answers your questions!

Comment: thanks! Your new answer is really detailed and exactly what I was looking for (for Python, anyway). +1!

Answer (score 6):

Perl strings definitely are not immutable.  Each string has a buffer, the initial offset of the string in the buffer, the length of buffer, and the amount of the buffer used.  Additionally, for utf8 strings, the character length is cached when it needs to be calculated.  At one point, there was some caching of additional character offset to byte offset information too, but I'm not certain that's still in place.

If the buffer needs to be increased, it reallocs it.  Perl on many platforms knows the granularity of the system malloc, so it can allocate a, say, 14 byte buffer for a 11 byte string, knowing that that won't actually take any additional memory.

The initial offset allows O(1) removal of data from the beginning of the string.

Comment: So they're basically implemented the same way as Perl arrays (room to grow on both sides, amortized O(1) appending of characters to either side, etc...)?

Comment: No, I think string buffers are more conservatively allocated.