# Python: how fast are slices and merging of arrays?

Tags: python

Subj. Are they implemented in trivial way with complexity O(N) or they are faster?

Comment: (a) What do you mean? Show some code (b) Feel free to time it yourself, and show that too.

Comment: What "arrays" are you talking about?  Please show some code.

Comment: Do you actually mean "arrays" or do you really mean "lists"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming by "array" you mean "list", getting a slice is O(k) (where k is the number of elements in the slice, as opposed to the number of elements in the whole list).

If by "merging" you mean creating a new list with the elements in 2 lists, yes, this would be O(n).

Reference: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 1):

Both slicing and merging are O(n) operations in Python as both require new lists to be created. There's a lot of good discussion on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364430/how-are-basic-data-types-strings-and-integers-implemented-in-python-and-perl).